# Can not provide context for dagger injection

Tags: android, dagger-2, androidinjector

I'm new in dagger , I want to inject context and network (using retrofit) in my classes .

this is my code so far :

```
   @Module
// Safe here as we are dealing with a Dagger 2 module
@Suppress("unused")
object NetworkModule {
    @Provides
    @Reusable
    @JvmStatic
    internal fun provideMainApi(retrofit: Retrofit): MainApi {
        return retrofit.create(MainApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Reusable
    @JvmStatic
    internal fun provideRetrofitInterface(): Retrofit {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }
}

@Module
class AppModule(private val app: Application) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication() = app
}
```

this is my component :

```
    @Singleton
@dagger.Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, NetworkModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    ///for injecting retrofit network
    fun injectMain(mainRepository: MainRepository)

    @dagger.Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): AppComponent

        fun networkModule(networkModule: NetworkModule): Builder
        fun appModule(appModule: AppModule):Builder
    }

}
```

I want to use it in my repository , I've a baseRepository :

```
    open class BaseRepository {
    private val injector: AppComponent = DaggerAppComponent
        .builder()
        .networkModule(NetworkModule)
        .build()

    init {
        inject()
    }

    private fun inject() {
        when (this) {
            is MainRepository -> injector.injectMain(this)
        }
    }

}
```

when I run the app , I get this error "module.AppModule must be set"

I understand the error and I should provie appMOdule in my base repository but the problem is I don't have any application or context in base repository

how should I fix this ?

the second problem I've is this , I've heard that I should once make the dagger and use it in my entire app and I shouldn't make it every time , it means I should use application for that .

but how can I use injector in an application class , it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would go through this project and see there how everything is done.

https://github.com/google/iosched

Here is explained what this project is about:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/google-i-o-2018-app-architecture-and-testing-f546e37fc7eb

Also you can check the Dagger branch ot this projec:

https://github.com/android/architecture-samples

It was all done by Jose Alcerreca and some other guys. These are the guidelines of Google about Android and there will be the answer of most of your questions.

**but how can I use injector in an application class , it doesn't make sense** There is a DaggerApplication class which you can extend and inject your App class however you want.

And I am telling you all of this, because I think you have learned Dagger from old sources. I would have changed a lot of stuff in your code.

Also I am using Dagger since 1.5 years and I have never ever written such a code like the one in: BaseRepository. I use only and only @Inject annotations and that is all throuhg my classes which are not Dagger related. Creating a Component in a Repository? -> Never!

This is how your classes should end up everywhere.

```
class Repostory @Inject constructor(
private val dependency1: Dependency1 
) {}

class Activity {
@Inject lateinit var dependency2: Dependency2
}
```